# Internet loses connectivity when steam is launched

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 whenever I launch steam or start a steam download I lose internet connectivity. Specifically I can no longer ping my default gateway.

If I reconnect to the wireless it will restart the connection and work fine after that until I start a steam download, whenever there is a steam download it will randomly drop the connection.

It never says that I've been disconnected from the wireless network I can just no longer ping the default gateway.

Thanks for reading and I'm happy to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem (tried with 12.04 ans 13.10)
After a short download time in steam, the connection drops steadily, until it's gone.

I tried Ethernet, Wifi, Steam Linux and Steam with Wine, it's no difference.

Only temporary solution I got was limiting the download speed in the steam settings to max. 256 kb/ 512kb / 1GB. Ironically it is most stable with 256 kb ...